# How to hide one of the radiobutton in radiobutton list?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Let say I want to hide one of the radio buttons with value 0, what code can make it visible = false? I was using Javascript, C# and ASP.NET.

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2"> 2&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3"> 3&nbsp</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4"> 4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Enabled="False">

foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
    var rbl = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rblSelect");
    var selectedValue = int.Parse(rbl.SelectedItem.Value);
    var selectedText = rbl.SelectedItem.Text;
    var selectedIndex = rbl.SelectedIndex;
    rbl.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This : From `CodeBehind`

```
MyRadioButtonList.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("visibility", "hidden");
```

**EDIT:**

```
int count = 0; //index of item tobe hidden
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
{


    var rbl = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rblSelect");
    var selectedValue = int.Parse(rbl.SelectedItem.Value);
    var selectedText = rbl.SelectedItem.Text;
    var selectedIndex = rbl.SelectedIndex;

    if(count == 0)
       rbl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("visibility", "hidden");

    count++;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question already, but still same couldn't hide it.

Comment: I ended up using : MyRadioButtonList.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
rbl.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use the following:

```
MyRadioButtonList.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it's possible to hide it with ".style.display"

```
var radio = document.getElementById('idOfYourRadiobutton');
radio.style.display = 'none'; // to hide
radio.style.display = 'block'; // to show
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the code as follows:

```
rdBtn.items.remove("name_of_the_item");
```

In this case, the `rdBtn` is the `RadioButtonList ID`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you don't want to display it:

```
ListView1.Items.FindByValue("0").Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none")
```

Changes `("display", "none")` to `("visibility", "hidden")` to hide it.

*What is the different between hide and none display?*
Well, if you hide a radio button between two other radio buttons, there is still a space between two those button. If you don't display it, there is no such weird space.